how to achieve this text flows in Flutter
enter image description hereplease can you help me how can I build such a design in Flutter, I actually build the most of it, but the problem is I don't know how to place the main text "Coffee so good, your taste buds will love it." over the main image as you see here in the photo. I tried Stack but it doesn't work or I didn't use it properly. please help me in this, I actually have a problem with flutter layouts I see it a little bit challenging, so any advices ?
and here is my code
class OnBoardingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoardingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            image: const AssetImage(TImages.onBoardingImage1),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: THelperFunctions.screenWidth(),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                      Colors.black.withOpacity(0.95),
                    ]),
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const Text(
                    'Coffee so good, your taste buds will love it.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: TColors.textWhite,
                      fontSize: 34,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  const Text('sub text'),
                  ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('click'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

I tried to use Stack to solve the problem and position the text but it didn't work with me

By changing your code a little it looks quite similar to the image, I have commented on the changes I have made to your code.




import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    THelperFunctions.screenWidthValue = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: OnBoardingScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OnBoardingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoardingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // 1 change Column to Stack
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Image(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            image: const AssetImage(TImages.onBoardingImage1),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          //2 Remove Expanded
          Container(
            width: THelperFunctions.screenWidth(),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              //3 change gradient
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  end: const Alignment(0, -0.2),
                  colors: [
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(1),
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0),
                  ]),
            ),
            child: Column(
              //4 change mainAxisAlignment to center
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                //5 add spacer
                const Spacer(),
                //6 Add Padding to the text
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, right: 60),
                  child: Text(
                    'Coffee so good, your taste buds will love it.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: TColors.textWhite,
                      fontSize: 34,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                //7 Add padding
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 60, right: 60),
                  child: Text(
                      'The best grain, the finest roast, the powerful flavor',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: TColors.textGrey,
                        fontSize: 14,
                      )),
                ),
                //8 Change ElevatedButton to MaterialButton
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                      color: const Color(0xFFc17d53),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: const SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 65,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "Get Started",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: TColors.textWhite,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TColors {
  static const Color textWhite = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
  static const Color textGrey = Color.fromARGB(255, 148, 146, 146);
}

class TImages {
  static const String onBoardingImage1 = 'images/background.jpg';
}

class THelperFunctions {
  static double screenWidthValue = 1000;

  static double screenWidth() {
    return screenWidthValue;
  }
}

images/background.jpg
:

Start from here:
Result :

Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: [
        DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.black, Colors.transparent],
              begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              end: Alignment.topCenter,
            ),
          ),
          child: Image.network('https://images.pexels.com/photos/312418/pexels-photo-312418.jpeg?', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: SizedBox.shrink()), // top part keep it empty
              Text('Coffe is so good, drink it boiled', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium?.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white
              ),),
              Text('Drink it now', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),),
              FilledButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Text('Get Started'),
              )


            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );


The full design :

class OnBoardingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const OnBoardingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: context.screenHeight * .7,
              child: Image.asset(
                "asstes/images/app_images/profile/pexels-chevanon-312418.jpg",
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: context.screenHeight * .6,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                    Colors.black,
                    Colors.black,
                    Colors.black,
                    Colors.black,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: context.screenHeight * .58,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Coffee so good, your taste buds will love it.',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontFamily: FontFamily.mainFont,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                const Text(
                  'The bset grain, the finst roast, the powerfull flavour',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 16,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: context.screenWidth * .8,
                  height: context.screenHeight * .07,
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    color: const Color(0xFFECB159),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      "CLICK",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

